# How can I LINQ outer join two collections?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
var rowData = companies.Select(
    t => new CompanyDetail
    {
        CompanyID = t.Title,
        Subjects = subjects.Count ( u => t.RowKey == "0000" + u.PartitionKey) 
    }).ToList();

   public class CompanyDetail
    {
        [DisplayName("Company")]
        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Subjects")]
        public Int32 Subjects { get; set; }
    }
```

The query output looks like this:

```
CompanyID  Subjects
1          2
2          4
3          1
```

However I have a problem if the company has no subjects. I would like to see:

```
CompanyID  Subjects
1          2
2          4
3          1
4          0
```

Is there a way that I can convert this LINQ query into an outer join so it always reports every company and then gives a count of how many subjects are connected through the row and partitionkey connector?

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer this without knowing what LINQ provider you are using - your query would work as you expect in LINQ to Objects, for example.

Perhaps it would be worth a try to use an explicit `GroupJoin` to convince the provider to give you empty groups:

```
var rowData = from company in companies 
              join subject in subjects 
                           on company.RowKey equals "0000" + subject.PartitionKey
                         into companySubjectGroup
              select new
              {
                  CompanyID = company.Title,
                  Subjects = companySubjectGroup.Count()
              };
```

Comment: Sorry I maybe missed out the information that you need. I am using Azure table storage so I guess it would be LINQ to objects. No SQL involved.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure table storage, but I seriously doubt that the query you have provided is a LINQ to Objects query. If it *really* is, then the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: companies and subjects are collections of the company and subject objects.

Comment: Yes, but are you sure they are purely in-memory collections (and that the queries on them bind to LINQ to Objects)? Anyway, did you try my suggestion?